# How to add additional props to a React element passed in as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am passing a react element as a prop to another element. In the child element that receives the prop, I need to set additional props to that element.

For example:

**Parent class**

```
class Menu Extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="Menu">
                <MenuItem icon={<MdInbox />} />
                <MenuItem icon={<MdDrafts />} />
                <MenuItem icon={<MdTrash />} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Child class**

```
class MenuItem Extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="MenuItem">
                {this.props.icon} // I want to set the icon's size prop here
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`this.props.icon` is a React element (`<MdInbox />`, `<MdTrash />`, etc), and it allows for a property `size`. I want to set the `size` property in the `MenuItem` class, as opposed to passing the prop in from the parent like this: `<MenuItem icon={<MdInbox size={24} />}`. I'd prefer just to set the size in one place only, within the `MenuItem` class.

Comment: React Element is immutable, therefore you cannot pass additional props or change it afterwards (reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#elements)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Pass in the component constructor instead of an instance:

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="Menu">
                <MenuItem icon={MdInbox} />
                <MenuItem icon={MdDrafts} />
                <MenuItem icon={MdTrash} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The child class:

```
class MenuItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // This constant must begin with a capital,
        // it’s how React distinguishes HTML elements from components.
        const Icon = this.props.icon;
        return(
            <div className="MenuItem">
                <Icon size={24} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, I actually like this resolution better :-) The only concern would be if the op wanted to add other data specific to the type (not called out in the example though)

Comment: Thanks! As for adding other props, it is possible to use **React.cloneElement**, i.e.: `React.cloneElement(Icon, { onClick: this.open, size: 24 })`.

Comment: It actually doesn't work for me. My App crashes for some reason. Is there a related documentation for this usage?

Comment: @Alex, that will be too specific to your application, I think you need a new question.

Comment: @Denis i think we need a function while passing icon prop in MenuItem, else react throws error saying expected function/class got object.

Comment: Could you update your solution for functional components as well, if your know how to do that? Would be great

Comment: @Tobi, class vs functional components has zero impact on this question and this solution. I suggest to look for guidance on functional components elsewhere.

Comment: @Denis , using your example, do you know of a way to pass props to MdInbox in Menu component, **and** in MenuItem component ?

Answer (score 26):

You can set icon size with `React.cloneElement` API

```js
class MenuItem Extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="MenuItem">
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.icon, { size: 24 })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer as it sticks to the format of the prop passed in (node, instead of elementType).

Answer (score 1):

You can also just pass the component and props to the child elemnt, fully destructure your component and props, then render it as a JSX element. You then can spread your props into the passed component. This way your child component reusable and you can change its props from the parent component.

```js
class Menu extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return(
                <div className="Menu">
                    <MenuItem Icon={MdInbox} size={24}/>
                    <MenuItem Icon={MdDrafts} size={24} />
                    <MenuItem Icon={MdTrash} size={24}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

The child class:

    class MenuItem extends React.Component {
        render() {
            // This constant must begin with a capital,
            // Use JS ...rest operator to seperate Icon from remaining props
            const {Icon, ...remainingProps} = this.props;
            return(
                <div className="MenuItem">
                    <Icon {...remainingProps}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```